# How to add Filter to Slicer to display the calculated Measure based on selection using Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am totally new to Power BI and struggling with Slicer. I have the below requirement:

I have 4 columns Starting From, Destination, Distance KM. For this, I need to add a slicer. If the user clicks on Distance KM, then the chart has to be updated with Distance KM values. Now here comes the trick. I also want to display a column Distance in Miles based on the Distance KM calculation(the KM has to be displayed in Miles). So, whenever user clicks on Distance KM(in slicer), it should show the chart with KM data, if the user clicks on Miles(in slicer), then the chart should be populated with Miles information. I need to do this using slicer in power bi. Trying to achieve this since a while but couldn't get through it.

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only list three columns after stating your data has four, but I believe this should work:

You need to create a new table for the slicer. Within the Home tab select "Enter Data". Enter the values you want to be able to select from (I named the table DistanceSlicer). Load that table and create a slicer with it.

[image]

Now you can create a new measure based on this slicer selection. Within the Modeling tab select "New Measure".

```
SelectedMeasure =
IF (
    VALUES ( DistanceSlicer[Measure] ) = "Kilometers",
    SUM ( Table1[Distance KM] ),
    SUM ( Table1[Distance Miles] )
)
```

Now use this measure in your table/chart and it should update based on your slicer selection.